# Getting: Error: QChipsInput while import QChipsInput component

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

After adding QChipsInput to my quasar.conf.js framework like below:

```
    framework: {
      config: {},
      components: ['QChipsInput'],
      plugins: [
        'Notify'
      ]
    },
```

It acc. to: https://v0-17.quasar-framework.org/components/chips-input.html

I'm getting:

```
 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./.quasar/quasar-user-options.js

Error: QChipsInput

  - import-transformation.js:6 module.exports
    [frontend]/[quasar]/dist/transforms/import-transformation.js:6:11
  - loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:18 
    [frontend]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:18:40
  - Array.map
  - loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:10 
    [frontend]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:10:8
  - String.replace
  - loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:7 Object.module.exports
    [frontend]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/loader.js.transform-quasar-imports.js:7:30

 App •  COMPILATION FAILED  • Please check the log above for details.
```

App package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "quasar": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0"
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QChipsInput is deprecated. Use QInput.